# Warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size

Tags: c, pointers, types, casting

I wrote the following code:

```
struct DVDARRAY
{
    int length;
    pDVD* dvds;
};

typedef struct DVDARRAY DVDARRAY_t;

//...
int main() 
{
    int i;
    char c;
    DVDARRAY_t* dvds;
    poDAOproperties props;
    props = get_dao_properties();
    dvds = (DVDARRAY_t*) DVDDAO_read_raw_filter(props, "id = 1");
    printf("title->: %s", dvds->dvds[0]->title);
}
```

and in another file the following is defined:

```
DVDARRAY_t* DVDDAO_read_raw_filter(poDAOproperties properties, char* filter)
{
    DVDARRAY_t *dvds;
    // ...some code...
    dvds = malloc(sizeof(DVDARRAY_t));
    // ...some code...
    return dvds;
}
```

Now my question: when I try to compile these files I get the following warning:

```
src/main.c: In Funktion »main«:
src/main.c:80:9: warning: cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast]
```

Line 80 of main.c is exactly that line:

```
dvds = (DVDARRAY_t*) DVDDAO_read_raw_filter(props, "id = 1");
```

What can I do?

Comment: I don't speak German. Could you please translate the error message to English, French, Latin or Hungarian?

Comment: Do us a favour and use `LANG=C gcc` when posting to SO

Comment: Is the struct DVDARRAY_t defined in both files?

Comment: I dont think you need that extra cast when you call the function. Does the program produce correct output?

Comment: DVDARRAY_t is defined in DVD.h wich is included as well in main.c as in DVDDAO.c...

Comment: The output of the program is correct though...

Comment: i get the warning without casting, too

Comment: Compile with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` (`-std=c1x` for gcc < 4.7) and `-pedantic-errors`. Then the compiler won't let you use undeclared functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not list the file names above so I will just call them `main.c` and `dvd.c`.

In `main.c`, you make a call to the otherwise undeclared function `DVDDAO_read_raw_filter`.  This tells the compiler to assume that the function exists, has an unknown (but fixed) set of arguments, and has a return value of type `int`.

In `dvd.c` you define the function `DVDDAO_read_raw_filter` with fixed (and known) arguments, returning type `DVDARRAY_t*`.  (Presumably you have to repeat the definition of `DVDARRAY_t` first.)

Note that `main.c` believes something untrue about `DVDDAO_read_raw_filter`, namely, that it has return type `int`.  This is causing your compile-time diagnostic.  By luck (you can decide for yourself whether this is good or bad luck :-) ) the program runs successfully in spite of this incorrect belief.

To fix the problem, tell `main.c` about the function before calling it, i.e., declare it.  You can also get a more explicit warning from gcc by adding `-Wimplicit-function-declaration` to your compile-time flags.

In general, it's a good idea to put `struct` definitions, `typedef`s, and function declarations into a header file (e.g., `dvd.h`) and then `#include` that header in the various C source files that make use of the definitions and declarations.  That way the compiler can compare the function declarations against the function definitions, and you need not repeat the contents of `struct`s and the names of `typedef`s in multiple `.c` files.

Comment: I cutted main.c in many parts. So you couldnt see that main.c already includes DVDDAO.c (thats my name ;-) )

Comment: You really was right. I included "DVD.h" where the struct DVD was defined but not the file "DVDDAO.h" thanks for your answer!

Answer (score -1):

If you are just trying to make things work...

```
unsigned char *temp; 
int number; 

temp = someArr[y][x].charAtThisLoc;
number = (int)(size_t)temp;
```

other solutions didn't work for me.